# Not able to post Ajax form values to the controller in mvc4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a modal popup using partial views and ajax. my View is

```
    <a href="Verify" id="myLink1">Verify</a>
    <div id="myDialog1" title="Verify Mobile Number" style="display: none">
     @{
Model.MobileVerificationModelDetails.MobileVerifyUpdateTargetID = "myDialog1";                                  
     }
  @Html.Partial("_MobileVerifyPopup(MobileVerificationModel)Model.MobileVerificationModelDetails)
```

and the partial view is

```
@model werWebApplication.Models.MobileVerificationModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Mobile", "Verification", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "myDialog1", OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }))
{
    <fieldset>

        <legend>Veify Mobile Number</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MobileNo)</td>
                <td>@Html.Encode(Model.MobileNo)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MobileNo)</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.Label("Verification  Code")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VerificationCode)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            <td>   <input type="submit" value="verify" /></td>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
}
```

my js code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $("#myDialog1").dialog({
                 autoOpen: false,

                 show: 'fade',
                 hide: 'fade',
                   modal: false,
                 width: 400,
                 draggable: false,
                 minHeight: 200,
                 position: [700, 200]


             $("#myLink1").click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $("#myDialog1").dialog("open");
                 return false;
             });

             function onSuccess() {
                 $("#myDialog1").dialog("close")
             }
         });
    </script>
```

and my controller code is

```
 public ActionResult Mobile(MobileVerificationModel model)
        {
           return PartialView("_MobileVerifyPopup",model);
}
```

When I am clicking on verify button I am the popup is appearing. But the thing is I am not able to get the values in Controller. Can someone please help me to post the values in mvc4

Answer (score 0):

Is any controller action being hit at all?

If not, check if you have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in your page as this is needed for  `Ajax.BeginForm`. Also check you have the UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled property set to true in your web.config

Comment: no. i tried to debug it. verify button in the partial view is not submitting the values